# SSAS Cube - Create measure based on the a dimension attribute

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, data-warehouse, ssas

We have an analysis service cube contains:

1 Measure = All_Calls_Count

2 dimensions = Month  &  Call Status

The All_Calls_Count reflects the count of rows on the fact table as shown :
[image: Count of rows]

Is it possible to create another measure that count all rows with only Call_Status = Rejected ? How ?

The below picture shows the desired output when browsing the cube :
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try:

1. create a Calculated Member (clic on *Calculation* tab and then on
   *New Calculated Member*
2. define it with the MDX expression you want

In your case, it could look like that:
[image]

A more detailed example [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/analysis-services/lesson-6-1-defining-calculated-members).

Comment: Thanks @irimias so much that worked and got me the desired output. Just in case i needed to do that in the future ; is it possible to filter with more than one dimension for example Count for rejected + from country = USA ?

Thanks again for the guide and the provided